# MongoDB query array for element size and $elemMatch comparison

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I need to retrieve only records that have at least one element in the `format.prices` array and every elements `price` are between 0 and 0.99:

So this works fine for the `price` comparison:

```
{ 'formats.prices': { $not: { $elemMatch: { price: { $gt: 0, $lte: 0.99 } } } } }
```

But how can I add the condition like `$not: { $size: 0 }` to exclude also the `formats.prices` without elements at all?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended with this and it works fine, don't know if there is a better way:

```
{
    'formats.prices': { $not: { $elemMatch: { price: { $gt: 0, $lte: 0.99 } } } },
    'formats.prices.0.price': { $exists: true }
}
```

Comment: It's better like it is. Presuming you have an index on "formats.prices.price" ( which is probably a good idea considering you want to range query it anyway, albeit an exclusion right now ) then the `$exists` test here can actually use it, which `$not: { $size: 0 }` cannot. Seems though that for a positive price then it would be better to do a positive match `{ 'formats.prices.price': { $gt: 0.99 } }` unless your true intention is that no price in the array falls in that range. Which is actually the oposite to how you posed your question.

Comment: Thanks you very much @BlakesSeven glad it is the best option, for the intention of the app yes I mistook the question, because I need that no price falls in that range (and not at least one). (Updating it)